# Is it possible to put a Lotus Notes response document into a folder without its parent?

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a folder with the "Show response documents in a hierarchy" property deselected. When I try and put a response document into this folder I get the error :-

"To move a response document to a folder that shows response hierarchy you need to move the topmost parent of the response"

But the folder does not show a response hierarchy!

If I turn the property on I get the same error (which now makes more sense) and, if I move the parent document into the folder then all child responses also appear (which is expected behaviour).

But is there a way of getting the responses into a folder without the parent document?

Comment: Have you tried locating the response document in a flat view and moving it from their into the folder?

Comment: The Notes client crashed whilst I was trying to close it. On restarting it I tried your suggestion - which works. In fact my agent (that uses dc.PuAllInFolder and was previously giving the error above) also now seems to work. Very strange! Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: In my experience, developing applications with "Response" feature is some problematic. I never use it because problems like you're having.

My suggestions is, if it's possible, redesign your app and don't use responses. You can use a field "ParentKey" for create the relation between the documents and categorized views to show them.